# Cannot run R.exe in Powershell

Tags: r, windows, powershell

I often find it more useful to run R on the command line (windows). However when I try it in Powershell I tend to run into problems, but this is easily overcome by first running `cmd` and then it works.

This is the error I get when I do `R CMD BATCH`

```
Invoke-History: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'BATCH'
```

I later realised that `r` is an alias that returns the immediate past command, hence my inability to run R.

Subsequently, I found that using the full filename for the executable (i.e. `R.exe`) or using Rcmd.exe (i.e. `Rcmd BATCH ...`) worked.

However, I'm just curious, is there a work around, in case one runs into similar conflicts?

Comment: Do you want to run an R session in terminal or run R scripts at command line?

Comment: My intention is to run R CMD with its options like build, INSTALL, check, etc.

Comment: I think you found the workaround: use the full filename, including the extension

Answer (score 9):

To start R in powershell:

```
R.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. I've since learned to use R in PowerShell or cmd.exe by running `rterm`.

Comment: If you need to enter R.exe in your system %PATH%, just restarting the installer will remind you where the binary is. Note that just typing `R` invokes PowerShell's history feature, which masks the executable.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround would be fully defining your calls.

```
& "path\to the\r.exe" arg1 arg2 etc
```

Alternatively,

```
$P = @{
  FilePath="path\to the\r.exe"
  ArgumentList=@('arg1','arg2')
}
Start-Process @P
```

Comment: Thanks. One of the reasons I asked this question is due to an unrelated issue wherein I cannot run 7-Zip's `7z` in PS 2.0, while it works perfectly when I run it in `cmd`. So I am unable to use a script containing it.

Comment: Do you get errors?  I haven't run into any issues with the 7z cli in ps2 scripts

Comment: It's on my workplace machine. When I get there tomorrow, I will post the error for all to see. Thanks, again.

Comment: I am aware that PS 2.0 is being deprecated, but I think it may be worth pointing out, even if it's for academic interest.

Comment: @VictorOrdu I'm also stuck on v2 in my workplace for the time being.

Comment: The error I get when I run `7z` in PS 2.0: `Bad numeric constant: 7. At line;1 char:2  + 7 <<<< z   + CategoryInfo             :  ParserError: <7:String>  [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant`. Note that this error occurs even if I give the full filename. But in `cmd` it runs without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on linux, where there is no file extension for executables, so that didn't help, but still there are two options:

- `/usr/bin/R` if it is installed in the usual location
- `Start-Process R` (the `start-process` cmdlet does not need to be capitalized)