# Unable to run 7-Zip in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, 7zip

This came up in a discussion on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905670/cannot-run-r-exe-in-powershell) I asked on running executables in Windows Powershell

Whenever I run `7z` in my workplace machine that has PS 2.0, I get this error

```
Bad numeric constant: 7.
At line;1 char:2
+ 7 <<<< z
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: <7:String> [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant.
```

Note that this error occurs even if I give the full filename `7z.exe`. However, if I go into Command Line mode by entering `cmd` it works without any problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
& "Path\to\7z.exe" arg1 arg2 etc
```

It sounds like PowerShell is trying to interpret your `[String]` literally as an `[Int]`

Comment: Yass! Thank you it worked! So in this case there is no short way to running it...

Comment: @VictorOrdu You could try quoting the path\exe, but to my knowledge they didn't add native interpretation until PSv3.

Comment: @VictorOrdu If this answered your question, kindly click the green checkmark next to the answer.